# How to call for a method with parameters?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, call

Okay so, I want to make a program that can find both the discriminant of a quadratic equation as well as the number of roots. I so far created the program to find the discriminant, but i'm having trouble calling the method to find the number of roots. Can someone please explain to me how this is done? Thanks.

```
 public class quadMethods
 {
     public static void main (String args[])
     {
         new quadMethods ();
     }


     public quadMethods ()
     {
         System.out.println ("The discriminant is: " + discrim (1, 6, 8));
         System.out.println ("The number of roots is: " + numRoots (1, 6, 8));
     }
  public double discrim (double a, double b, double c)
     { //assumes ax^2+bx+c=0
         //returns the discriminant of the quadratic equation
         //b*b-4*a*c
         //replace the return 1
    double discriminant = b*b-4*a*c;    
         return discriminant;
     }


     public int numRoots (double a, double b, double c)
     { //assumes ax^2+bx+c=0
         //returns the number of roots for the quadratic equation
         //call discrim method, make an if to return 0, 1, or 2.
         //replace the return 1
  return 1;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do not edit your question like that, someone has taken time to answer you.

Comment: Sorry. I want to delete this post, but I can't seem to do so.

Comment: No since you have an accepted answer, what the reason for deleting?

Comment: Well it helped solve my problem and I accepted the solution, so I don't want any more notifications from the question.

Comment: Ok I have sent close request for unclear / typo (unlikely to help future visitors.), Lets hope we get some votes and no one will be able to answer anymore.

Comment: Thanksssssssssssss

Comment: By the way, can you send close requests for my other 3 questions as well. It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm going to bed now (I have no more close votes), I will check them out tomorrow, if I think they should be closed as this question, I will vote accordingly.

Comment: KK                        aii thanks again

Comment: @asdfghjkl9999 that's a bit of a weird use of stackoverflow, you ask, you get an answer and then you delete? This site wasn't meant for that, was meant to help future users with similar issues to find the question and the answer again, that is, to help you today but to help others as well tomorrow. If then your question wouldn't help others, then it might be closed

Comment: Ya I don't think this program will help other future users though so the question might as well get closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh by the way, the answer I was looking for was:

```
public double discrim (double a, double b, double c)
{ 
  return (b*b)-(4*a*c);
}


public int numRoots (double a, double b, double c)
{ 
double d = discrim (a,b,c);
if (d>0)
 return 2;
else if (d<0)
 return 0;
else
 return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    quadMethods instance = new quadMethods();

    System.out.println(instance.discrim(1.0, 2.0, 3.0));

    int myRoots = instance.numRoots(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
}
```

Comment: i don't get it. when i try to add my code to find the number of roots, it still says no field named "discriminant" was found

Comment: It shouldn't do that... can you share the full error details?

Comment: My bad. That's not what it does. But instead the output keeps on looping "The discriminant is: 4.0" instead of actually providing the number of roots that the quadratic equation has.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an  object and call the method

```
quadMethods qMet =new quadMethods ();
qMet.numRoots (...);
```

What you are doing until now I'd just creating an object ( but anonymously)...

Comment: Wait but it says "Missing ';' at end of statement" when i typed "qMet.numRoots"